# Injecting Dependencies : ASP.net Webforms using an MVP pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, webforms, mvp

I'm struggling to implement the injection of dependencies using ASP.net.  I have created a simple project in winforms which uses the MVP Passive View pattern.  I see lots of variations of this pattern online. Many examples I see have the View responsible for instantiating the Presenter.  Others have the Presenter create the View.  I chose to let a separate winforms project run first and on the click of a button, create my View, Model and Presenter and have the view passed in to the Presenters constructor.  This let me avoid direct references between the three layers such that they only kept a reference to a Library of Interfaces.  So far so good and everything worked as hoped.  I had heard that if I had managed to keep the View as "dumb" as possible that moving to ASP.net would not be too difficult since the main logic presided in the Presenter.

My next move was to recreate the solution in ASP.net webforms and just replace the UI/View with a webform in whoch the code-behind implemented my IView Interface.  All my classes successfully compiled without issue but when I run the program I get a NullReferenceException :object reference not set to an instance of an object.  This happens as the Presenter tries to set the view property of a textbox.  It seems like the textbox has not been created.  If I compare the start sequence of the webforms app with the winforms app then I see that the winforms app runs through the View when it is created and registers each control and property.  This does not happen with the webform even though I use the same approach for both.

Here is the separate webform which loads first:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using POCOClassLibrary;
using InterfaceLibrary;
using AppointmentModel;
using AppointmentsPresenter;
using WebFormMVP;

namespace WebDriver
{
    public partial class WebDriver : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnLaunch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IAppointmentView view = new frmAppointmentView();
            IAppointmentModel<Appointment> model = new AppointmentsModel();
            new AppointmentPresenter(view, model);

            view.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

This loads and the button appears, next on clicking it reaches the Presenter class (not all shown here):

```
namespace AppointmentsPresenter
{
    //The Presenter is the go-between for the View and Model.  It sets the properties in the View to be displayed and
    //Stores and Gets the data from the Model. It responds to events raised by the View.
    public class AppointmentPresenter
    {
        private readonly IAppointmentView _view;                //references the View Interface
        private readonly IAppointmentModel<Appointment> _model; //references the Model Interface
        /// <summary>
        /// The List of Appointments is created and stored in the Model.  
        /// In reality we would be using a Database and not a List<>.
        /// </summary>
        private List<Appointment> appointments;

        //maintenace of state:
        private int currentIndex = 0;
        private bool isNew = true;

        private string navigationstatus = "next";
        ///Presenter constuctor which allows us to pass in the View and Model as interfaces - exposing their events,
        /// methods and properties.    
        public AppointmentPresenter(IAppointmentView view, IAppointmentModel<Appointment> model)  //dependencies passed into contructor 
        {

            this._view = view;
            this._model = model;

            Initialize();
        }
        private void Initialize()
        {
            appointments = _model.CreateList();         //Creates and returns List of Appointments in the Model
                                                        //lets us manipulate the List that the Model creates.
            _view.SaveAppointment += Save_Appointment;  //Subscribe to the View events.
            _view.NewAppointment += New_Appointment;
            _view.PreviousAppointment += Previous_Appointment;
            _view.NextAppointment += Next_Appointment;
            _view.YesButtonClick += YesButtonClicked;
            _view.NoButtonClick += NoButtonClicked;

            BlankAppointment();
            _view.StatusChange = "Ready";
        }
        private void BlankAppointment()
        {
            _view.AppointmentName = string.Empty;
            _view.Priority = "Low";
            _view.StartDate = null;
            _view.DueDate = null;
            _view.CompletionDate = null;
            _view.Completed = false;
        }
```

When it reaches the BlankAppointment() method and tries to set the _view.AppointmentName property is when things go awry and the NullReferenceException is thrown.

Here is some of the View, I have tried to remove the majority of logic outside and just implement properties and events here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using InterfaceLibrary;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace WebFormMVP 
{
    public partial class frmAppointmentView : System.Web.UI.Page, IAppointmentView
    {   
        public string AppointmentName
        {
            get { return txtAppointment.Text; }
            set { txtAppointment.Text = value; }
        }
        public string Priority
        {
            get { return cboPriority.Text; }
            set { cboPriority.Text = value; }
        }
        public string StartDate
        {
            get { return txtStartDate.Text; }
            set { txtStartDate.Text = value; }
        }
        public string DueDate
        {
            get { return txtDueDate.Text; }
            set { txtDueDate.Text = value; }
        }
        public string CompletionDate
        {
            get { return txtCompletionDate.Text; }
            set { txtCompletionDate.Text = value; }
        }
        public bool Completed
        {
            get { return chkCompleted.Checked; }
            set { chkCompleted.Checked = value; }
        }
        public bool isDirty { get; set; }

        public bool NewButtonVisible
        {
            set { btnNew.Visible = value; }
        }
        public bool SaveButtonVisible
        {
            set { btnSave.Visible = value; }
        }
        public bool NextButtonVisible
        {
            set { btnNext.Visible = value; }
        }
        public bool PreviousButtonVisible
        {
            set { btnPrevious.Visible = value; }
        }
        public bool YesButtonVisible
        {
            set { btnYes.Visible = value; }
        }
        public bool NoButtonVisible
        {
            set { btnNo.Visible = value; }
        }
        public string StatusChange
        {
            set { lblStatus.Text = value; }
        }

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> NewAppointment;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> NextAppointment;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> NoButtonClick;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> PreviousAppointment;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SaveAppointment;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> YesButtonClick;

        public void Show()
        {
            this.Show();
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.isDirty = false;
        }
        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SaveAppointment != null)
            {
                SaveAppointment(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (NewAppointment != null)
            {
                NewAppointment(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (PreviousAppointment != null)
            {
                PreviousAppointment(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (NextAppointment != null)
            {
                NextAppointment(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        private void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (YesButtonClick != null)
            {
                YesButtonClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        private void btnNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (NoButtonClick != null)
            {
                NoButtonClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        private void txtAppointment_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.isDirty = true;
        }
        private void cboPriority_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.isDirty = true;
        }
        private void txtStartDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.isDirty = true;
        }
        private void txtDueDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.isDirty = true;
        }
        private void txtCompletionDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.isDirty = true;
        }
        private void chkCompleted_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.isDirty = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Form my searches so far it seems like there may be a problem with implementing the injection into the Presenters constructor in webforms and that I would need to override the PageHandler class to resolve the dependencies however the examples I have looked at so far have the Presenter being created first by the View.  I would like to avoid this if at all possible and use a separate webform Page to instantiate the Model, View, Presenter and resolve the dependencies this way.

Apologies if I haven't been clear - I am very wet behind the ears with both MVP and ASP.net Webforms.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I am pretty confused as to how I might solve this puzzle. ;D

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use ASP.NET MVC, which is both similar to MVP and easier to use Dependency Injection with than WebForms?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm sure it would be the most appropriate way to go and I would certainly prefer to use ASP.NET MVC instead. However, for some unknown reason my teacher has forced us all to use webforms :C He wouldn't budge on this. He's a bit stuck in his ways and wouldn't let us use GitHub either - it had to be Team Foundation Server and nothing else.  Can it be done in WebForms or should I accept defeat?

Comment: According to [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net), one way is to put a separate composition root into each page. I have read about other approaches that use a custom HTTP handler, but when I tried that I ran into some issues with the HttpContext object having invalid information in it (I don't recall which properties) that prevented parts of the app from working. I suppose it is possible, though.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much for the help - I will look into the link you posted and see if I can work out how to add a composition root whatever that may be.  Is this something you have managed to do yourself? Again, thankyou.  Ah! I see it is a book and not a free source of info - I will scour the net some more and see if I can find out more...

Comment: Its not free, but worth more than 25 other books I have read combined.

Comment: That's a strong recommendation if ever I heard one :D Sold!